# What is the default XSLT transformer used in spring integration xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt

Using Spring Integration XML 3.0.0.RELEASE I have a XSLT transformer as such:

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="tm100Totm120aTransformation"
    xsl-resource="classpath:xsd/mailxml/xslt/tm120b_to_tm140a.xsl"
    result-transformer="resultToString"
    input-channel="validatedtm100Message"
    output-channel="validatedtm120aMessage"/>
```

Without specifying the `transformer-factory-class` attribute, how does Spring determine which TransformerFactory is actually used?

The JavaDoc for [TransformerFactory.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28%29) states:

> Obtain a new instance of a TransformerFactory. This static method creates a new factory instance This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the TransformerFactory implementation class to load:
>
> - Use the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with the key being the system property defined above. The jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for the first time.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in jars available to the runtime.
> - Platform default TransformerFactory instance.
>
> Once an application has obtained a reference to a TransformerFactory it can use the factory to configure and obtain transformer instances.

Does Spring follow this procedure? I can't seem to find the details of how Spring does this in the Spring docs.

P.S.

Upon debug inspection it appears my application is using `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` as the implementation. My understanding is that Xalan is included with the JRE (I'm using Java 1.6); is it reasonable to assume then that I am using the Platform default TransformerFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do a run using -Djaxp.debug=true and confirm what is going on via the logs.

The bootstrap process of finding a  XSLT implementation is part of Xalan and it's design of separating the API from the multiple possible implementations.

As such this is not part of Spring but of Xalan, and spring uses it indirectly by calling the transformer factory method you mentioned.

The fact that the package name of the implementation chosen contains internal means that the default implementation shipped with the JVM was chosen, which is the last option in the bootstrap process.

Comment: That's what I was looking to confirm, that int-xml:xslt-transformer did in fact use `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` (and therefore follows the described lookup procedure). Thanks.